# How to download google source code for android

Tags: android, python, windows, git, android-source

As you know, there is a list of several hundred projects in https://android.googlesource.com/. I'd like to download them all in windows machine. According to Google's document,

```
To install, initialize, and configure Repo:

$ curl https://storage.googleapis.com/git-repo-downloads/repo > ~/bin/repo
$ chmod a+x ~/bin/repo


To clone the entire platform, install repo, and run:

mkdir mydroid
cd mydroid
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest
repo sync
```

In my machine, however, I cannot "repo init" in Git Bash because it says it does not have python. I have python installed but git bash does not recognize it. **Note that I set the python directory to the system path too.** If anybody can give a tip, I would appreciate it. Thanks

UPDATE: I believe it's problem with new version of Git Bash for Windows. System path is not applied to Git Bash at all - I could easily test if system path worked with command prompt. Anyway, I tried this instead and it actually ran with error of course.

```
  /c/python27/python.exe  ../bin/repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest
```

The error message is

```
 $ /c/python27/python.exe ../bin/repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "../bin/repo", line 91, in <module>
    import readline
 ImportError: No module named readline
```

OK. I passed this error by installing pyreadline in windows:

```
 easy_install pyreadline
```

If you got an error, you must install setuptools from

```
 http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#files
```

And finally ran the command again to get this:

```
$ repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest
fatal: unable to start d:\mywork\dev\GoogleAndroid\working_dir\.repo\repo/main.py
fatal: [Errno 8] Exec format error
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With **one click**, download the latest code as `.tar.gz` file, from here
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+archive/master.tar.gz, the android could be found under `core` folder

**Edit**
Alternative here:
http://grepcode.com/project/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/

Just select the version then a download options within.

Comment: Why didn't you appear earlier. I am so wasted by now. Yeah I thought it should be this way but had no clue. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If you consider, as an example, this [other program "sympy"](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/wiki/Windows-development-using-git) which also needs git bash and python, it is only a matter to add python to your PATH *prior* to launching the git bash session.

> Install Python from:

http://python.org/download/

> by downloading the "Python 2.7 Windows installer" (or Python 2.6 or 2.5) and running it.
>   **Add python directory to your system environment path variable**
>   (`My Computer -> Advanced -> Environment Variables -> Path -> Edit`).

Note that the repo script itself must be in the path, as mentioned in the [Version Control page](http://source.android.com/source/version-control.html) of android:

> Repo is a repository management tool that we built on top of Git. Repo unifies the many Git repositories when necessary, does the uploads to our revision control system, and automates parts of the Android development workflow.
>   Repo is not meant to replace Git, only to make it easier to work with Git in the context of Android.
>   **The repo command is an executable Python script that you can put anywhere in your path**.

Comment: What makes me crazy is I did set all the things including system path and script directory. My guess is MingW which Git bash is running on does not recognize the python installation.

Comment: @TheFog: it should. Modify the `git-bash.bat` to see it `python --version` works in it. Or try using the `git-cmd.bat` to see if the problem persists in a non-bash environment.

Comment: @TheFog: it could also be a shebang issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547005/how-can-i-get-my-git-msysgit-on-windows-post-commit-script-to-invoke-my-python/1547240#1547240

Comment: I have the same issue and I have python27 in my PATH on win7, but I still get the same exact issue.  Any ideas?

Comment: @occas: beside the shebang, I don't see another reason for this issue right now.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if I should modify the "repo" file downloaded from curl or main.py.  I tried both but then get other errors.

Answer (score 1):

This answer explains how to fix this error:

```
fatal: unable to start c:\path\.repo\repo/main.py
fatal: [Errno 8] Exec format error
```

**Summary:** I finally used the `python` packaged by Cygwin. 
**Details:** Below is the full story.

The [tip from the `repo` bug tracking](http://code.google.com/p/git-repo/issues/detail?id=88#c2) is to add `'/c/app/Python27/python '`:

- line 136 in v1.20 
  `REPO_MAIN = '/c/app/Python27/python ' + S_repo + '/main.py'`
- line 735 in v1.20 (beginning of function `main`) 
   
  `wrapper_path = '/c/app/Python27/python ' + os.path.abspath(__file__)`

But we get the error `TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, NoneType found`

Therefore I reverted these changes above and performed the other changes below (on version 1.20):

- line 136, replaced single slash by double back-slash: 
  `REPO_MAIN = S_repo + '\\main.py'`
- line 766, added `python` absolute path as first element of `me`: 
      `me = ['C:\\app\\Python27\\python.exe', repo_main,` 
   
      `'--repo-dir=%s' % rel_repo_dir,` 
      `'--wrapper-version=%s' % ver_str,` 
      `'--wrapper-path=%s' % wrapper_path,` 
      `'--']`
- line 776, replaced `os.execv(repo_main, me)` by 
  `os.execv('C:\\app\\Python27\\python.exe', me)`

However we get still an error:

```
$ Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\path\.repo\repo\main.py", line 39, in <module>
    from subcmds.version import Version
  File "c:\path\.repo\repo\subcmds\__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    ['%s' % name])
  File "c:\path\.repo\repo\subcmds\forall.py", line 17, in <module>
    import fcntl
ImportError: No module named fcntl
```

The [Python v2.7 `fcntl` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/fcntl.html?highlight=fcntl#fcntl) says `fcntl` is available for platform Unix only.

I finally reverted again all changes in `repo` script and installed Cygwin including its `python` and `git` packages: it succeeded as a charm.

<s>But, as the *symlinks* simulated by Cygwin are not recognized by the MSysGit, we have to use the Cygwin `git`. And GUIs on top of `git` are not fully compliant with Cygwin `git`...</s>

(see also [my other post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18652851/938111))

**Edit:** 
[Cygwin can use native NTFS symlinks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18659632/938111) (just set `CYGWIN=winsymlinks:native` and be Admin). Therefore MSysGit can be used and any other GUI based on it :-)