# Is there a bug tracking tool used by git developers?

Tags: git

Is there some defect tracking tool that git developers use to track bugs, and can I file a bug somewhere?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bug tracker setup with Git integration?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40495/bug-tracker-setup-with-git-integration)

Comment: I think he refers to the git project, not projects using git as cvs.

Comment: Check http://git-scm.com

Answer (score 1):

If you want a bug tracker for your own project using git, checkout [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40495/bug-tracker-setup-with-git-integration). If however, you are looking to file a bug pertaining to git itself, you can post to the mailing list. More information can be found on their [site](http://git.or.cz/index.html#community).